# How to run .aspx file for a beginner

Tags: html

All,

I have very limited knowledge of .aspx and ultimately what I want to do is exactly this:

http://www.webonweboff.com/widgets/ajax/ajax_linked_selection.aspx

I appreciate the code is given in the link above, but I am only familiar with HTML and Javascript so when it starts to tell me .aspx and .cs code I get a little lost. Have done my homework and I guess i need to install something to run these programs. Naively, I only have notepad++ at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Joe

Comment: You should run through some of the tutorials at http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to go to http://www.asp.net/downloads and click the big green Install Now button. This will use the Microsoft Web Installer to download everything you need to get started with ASP.NET development (including Visual Studio Express which will take the place of notepad++!).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing visual web developer and create ASP.NET wesite in C#. You should be able to run these files.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Also try going through these tutorials

http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Answer (score 1):

ASPX is like CGI programming. Yes you need to install the ASP.NET developer studio in order to deploy your web application. It will then configure a default webserver on your local host where you can start playing with the code samples.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies - am downloading what you've mentioned and will give it a go once installed.